# Let R be a commutative non-trivial ring. Show that R is torsion-free iff R is an integral domain. Proof check.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

I have the following exercise:

Let R be a commutative non-trivial ring. Show that R is torsion-free (as a R-module) iff R is an integral domain.

So I assumed first R is torsion-free, so I take a non-zero element $r \in R$, then choose two elements $a,b \in R$ such that $ra = rb$ then we have that $r(a-b) = 0 \space$ (because  $r \neq 0$ and as R is torsion free if we have that $ a \in R$ non-zero and $r \in R$ then $ra = 0 \Rightarrow r=0$) $\Rightarrow a-b = 0 \Rightarrow a=b$ so we have that R is an integral domain.

For the converse we have that $ \forall a,b \in R \space a\neq 0 \neq b$ we have $ab \neq 0$ this because R is assumed an integral domain; so we take any $r \in R$ non-zero and $a \in R$ with $ar = 0$ so as $r \neq 0$ this implies (because R is a domain) that $a=0$, so we conclude R is torsion-free

Is my proof correct? As we are seeing modules in my algebra class this problems seems to be trivial, and I think that I must be skipping something. Please clarify.

Comment: How $r(a-b)=0$ and $r \neq 0$ implies that $a-b=0$? You need to put this in your proof. Also, what about $\textrm{integral domain} \implies \textrm{torsion-free}$?

Comment: Ah, yes I supposed it was clear that because R was torsion-free if $a \in R$ non-zero and $r \in R$ then $ra = 0 \Rightarrow r = 0$ lemme edit that! :)

Comment: It would be good to clarify that when you say "torsion-free" here you mean as an $R$-module. With no further qualifiers you could also mean that $R$ is torsion-free as an abelian group in which case the statement would be false.